# how to execute pgsql script in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

I want to execute some **pgScript** directly from the *pgAdmin* editor UI.

```
FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
   PRINT i; -- i will take on the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 within the loop
END LOOP;
```

But I always got

```
[ERROR    ] 1.0: syntax error, unexpected character
```

I also tried to wrap the code with **do$$...$$**, but does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

apart from [Clodoaldo Neto's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26117708/3682599).You can try this also

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
 FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
       RAISE NOTICE '%', i; -- i will take on the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 within the loop
 END LOOP;
END
$$
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `PRINT` command. Use `raise notice` instead.

```
create function f()
returns void as $$
begin
    FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
       raise notice '%', i; -- i will take on the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 within the loop
    END LOOP;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html

Comment: err..I thought with anonymous block, it is not necessary to create a function for every short script...no?

Comment: @davidshen84 ... but you need a `DO` block, you can't just write PL/PgSQL directly.